# Handling Concurrency for a JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am developing a JavaFX application which does the following process in sequence when the button is clicked.

1. Update table (DB2) thru JDBC connecton
2. Execute the Mainframe (Z/OS) Jobs
3. Update table again to complete the process

There are no issues with single user. But the issue is when there are concurrent users.

The problem i am facing is the above tasks should not be concurrent. If User1 is running the above tasks from the JavaFX application, User2 have to wait till all the processes of the User1 are completed. Otherwise, both users will not get the expected results.

How to handle the queue for a multi user application.

Comment: So the application is running using a Server?With peer to peer?LAN? How multiple users can use it simultaneously?Describe a little bit how it work for multiple users...so we can provide better answers.

Comment: It is a desktop application installed locally for each user. Application works when connected to the Company VPN. Once connected, Database acccessed thru JDBC and Z/OS jobs are executed via FTP connection.

Answer (score 0):

> ~~~>Solution 1

You can have a Server([ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)) which has a [Queue](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/blocking-queues.html).It has one Thread waiting for requests and one other executing one after other the requests.

Every time one user has to connect to database it sends one message to the Server for example (IP,PORT) .

The Server saves that message into the  Queue and so on.Synchronously the other Thread of the Server is getting and executing one by one messages from Queue.

> Example:

computer1 sends (192.345.22 , 52 )

computer1 sends (192.567.32 , 52 )

...

obviously the port is the same every time.

So only one user will be served at a time,but multiple users can send a message for job to do on Server.

When a message is extracted the 1,2,3 you mentioned in the question are done.That continues until the Queue is empty or unlimited if new messages are comming all the time.

Obviously the Server App has to be opened all the time so the whole think can work.

I know it is not the easiest thing to implement but you gonna learn a lot doing it..